# OnSizeChanged not raised on Release build

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I have created Portable class library with image cropping control for Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 and I have problem with control behavior in Release build.

When I navigate first time to page which contains created control `SizeChanged` event is not raised (so I can't properly observe `ActualWidth/ActualHeight`). It is raised when orientation changes, in debug mode or even when I navigate to other page and navigate back to this page (some kind of page navigation control cache?). I turned off code optimization in release build but it doesn't help so I guess it's not compiler optimalization issue. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found how to fix the issue (but not why does it happen). As I write custom control I can override `Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)` which surprisingly gives correct size. I have still no idea why does it happen, technically speaking SizeChanged should be raised - according to msdn "Layout processing routine" is: `measure` -> `arrange` -> `raise size changed if needed` -> `update layout`